# Scrollable view inside another scrollable view, android

Tags: android, list, listview, tableview, scrollable

Hi all and thanks for reading,

I've been trying to put a scrollable view (TableLayout inside a ScrollView) inside another scrollable view (LinearLayout inside a ScrollView).

This didn't work very well because the table was almost impossible to scroll. So I tried with a ListView instead but couldn't get it to work, but i'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

What I need to do is put the scrollable view (which shows a list of orders) in an activity with a main scrollable view including other views.

So to summarize...

Activity <- Main scrollable view <- Scrollable view as "order list" with fixed headers and other views

Can anyone point me to some good examples or give me one? And is it possible to put other views as main view in a ListActivity?

Big thanks!

Comment: DON'T, don't put scroll in scroll. Rethink your design please.

Comment: You can't do that, you can't put a `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView`.

Comment: Learned that the hard way. :) But there must be a way to put some kind of a scollable view inside a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to do is put the scrollable view (which shows a list of orders) in an activity with a main scrollable view including other views.

Putting scrollable things in other scrollable things infrequently works. Please come up with a UI design that does not require putting scrollable things in other scrollable things.

> But there must be a way to put some kind of a scollable view inside a ScrollView

You are mistaken.